# Can we compare two different strings for similarity using Google NLP API's?

Tags: google-cloud-nl

Example: 
String 1: Help me to track calls.
String 2: Assist me in call tracking.

These two strings have the same meaning but are not identical. Is there any way to find similarity between strings like these using Google Natural Language Processing Api's.

Answer (score 0):

The **Google Cloud Natural Language API** doesn't provide a specific feature to find similarities between two different strings; instead, this service offers the [Content Classification](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classifying-text) functionality that you can use to classify the strings into categories to then calculate the similarity between them based on their resulting content classification. You can find a helpful [Content Classification Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classify-text-tutorial) where is explained the process required to perform these tasks.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/), as well as take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Natural Language API feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187079&template=1011234) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.